# Make Bootstrap DatePicker ReadOnly after dateselect

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a requirement to make bootstrap datepicker readonly after selecting date. But I am not getting required behavior for the same. I have tried with change event and changeDate event of datepicker but none of them is working.

```
 $('#txtBookingDate').on('change', function (event) {
        $('#txtBookingDate').attr('readonly','readonly');
    });
```

And also ,

```
 $('#txtBookingDate').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function (e) {        
        $('#txtBookingDate').attr('readonly','readonly');
    });
```

What I want to achieve is to allow user only single time to select date i.e. Once user select date for first time then make datepicker readonly so user can't change date!

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove datepicker after selecting date first time and use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) like,

```
$('#txtBookingDate').datepicker().on('change', function (e) {        
     $(this).datepicker('remove')
            .prop('readonly',true);
});
```

Snippet,

```js
$('#txtBookingDate').datepicker().on('change', function(e) {
  $(this).datepicker('remove')
    .prop('readonly', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtBookingDate" />
```

You can use [enableOnReadonly:false](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enableonreadonly) option without removing the datepicker.

Comment: Before selecting the date datepicker is removed i.e. when I click on datepicker it just popsup and close and the datepicker becomes readonly ! :(

Comment: Great !! Its working properly as I want !! Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

You can use these `attr('readonly',true)` or `prop('readonly',true)` to make date input readonly. You can select one of them according to your jquery version.

```js
// if jquery version > 1.9
$('#txtBookingDate').on('change', function (event) {
        $('#txtBookingDate').prop('readonly',true);
});

// if jquery version < 1.9
$('#txtBookingDate').on('change', function (event) {
        $('#txtBookingDate').attr('readonly',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="txtBookingDate"></input>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , but I can't make it disable because I need that date value in Post and disabled elements are not posted while form submit ! :(

Comment: @Nikunj which version of jquery do you use

Comment: You should check your jquery version to select either .prop() or .attr()

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code snippet:**

```js
$('#txtBookingDate').datepicker({
            weekStart: 1,
            startDate: '01/01/2010',
            autoclose: true,
            "setDate": new Date(),
        }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
            $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
        });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-V0Nho4sjvYsznAMBVSBq2YuaQ8CDXv4FRdoIy+Yf4zk=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-FOV0q1Ks/eXoUwtkcN6OxWV4u9OSq7LDomNYnfF/0Ys=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
<input type="text" id="txtBookingDate"/>
```